# Writing multiple objects to csv 1 per line

Tags: java, csv, serialization, jackson

Im trying to write serialize a object to a multiline csv file. 
Now instead of 1 per line it writes all in 1 line.

Here is my code.

```
    PurchaseOrder po = new PurchaseOrder(entry);
    ArrayList<Object> l = Lists.newArrayList();
    l.add(po);
    l.add(new PurchaseOrder(entry));
    CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
    CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(PurchaseOrder.class);
    schema = schema.withColumnSeparator(',');
    ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(schema);
    File tempFile = new File("test.csv");
    FileOutputStream tempFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
    BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(tempFileOutputStream, 1024);
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(bufferedOutputStream, "UTF-8");          
    for(Object o : l) {
        writer.writeValue(outputStreamWriter, o);
    }
```

The reason for the ArrayList is that the end result needs to be generic as the ArrayList would need to be able to contain ant type of object.

This was the solution that worked in the end. Passing in a list is the way to do it

```
    PurchaseOrder po = new PurchaseOrder(entry);
    ArrayList<Object> l = Lists.newArrayList();
    l.add(po);
    l.add(new PurchaseOrder(entry));
    CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
    CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(PurchaseOrder.class);
    schema = schema.withColumnSeparator(',');
    ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(schema);
    File tempFile = new File("test.csv");
    FileOutputStream tempFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
    BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(tempFileOutputStream, 1024);
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(bufferedOutputStream, "UTF-8");          
    writer.writeValue(outputStreamWriter, l);
```

-------NEW PROBLEM-------
The above sollution works if its the same object. Now as its 2 different object each needing its own line the schema has to change proving more troublesome than I thought it would be.

Here is what Im trying at the moment without any success.

```
        ArrayList<Object> l = Lists.newArrayList();
        l.add(new PurchaseOrderE(entry));
        l.add(new PurchaseOrderL(entry));
        CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
        //CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(PurchaseOrderE.class);
        //schema = schema.withColumnSeparator(',');
        //schema = schema.withLineSeparator("");
        //ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(schema);
        File tempFile = new File("test.csv");
        //FileOutputStream tempFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        //BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(tempFileOutputStream, 1024);
        //OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(bufferedOutputStream, "UTF-8");
        //for(Object o : l) {
            //CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(o.getClass());
            //schema = schema.withColumnSeparator(',');
            //schema = schema.withLineSeparator("");
            ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer();
            FileOutputStream tempFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
            BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(tempFileOutputStream, 1024);
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(bufferedOutputStream, "UTF-8");
            writer.writeValue(outputStreamWriter, l);
        //}
```

The pieces commited out is what I have tried sofar without success. There has to be something Im missing as I cnt think that this great lib wnt provide a way to serialize different objects to the same file.

Comment: You are writing the list containing the PurchaseOrder objects. You could write the content of the list and when deserialize put all in a list. Something like for(Object o : l) --> write o

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper

Comment: I have tried looping over the list and writig the objects yet then it just overrides the 1st line. So then I end up with just one line with 1 object

Comment: What Im basically looking to do is have it start on a new line on each iteration

Comment: Have you tried schema.withLineSeparator(String sep)?

Comment: I have "\n", The issue now is just that the line ends in " and the newline starts with "

Comment: Maybe you can take a look what the api says: http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-csv/javadoc/2.0.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/csv/class-use/CsvSchema.html there are also a method withoutQuoteChar(Char c). Maybe you should try a few methods ;)

Comment: I have been following that api, here is a link to a gist that shows a working example https://gist.github.com/shsdev/11392809